# Inserting into BST from ArrayList will not work

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I'm having trouble with the Binary Search Tree.

I've read a textfile into an arrayList and am trying to put it into a Binary Search Tree but when I try calling the bst.insert function and then check to see by calling printTree, it shows up empty. Any help will be appreciated.

Here is the BST file

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class BST<AnyType extends Comparable<AnyType>>  {

    private BinaryNode<AnyType> root;

    public BST()
    {
        root = null;
    }

    public void insert (AnyType x)
    {
        root = insert(x, root);
    }

    public void remove(AnyType x)
    {
        root = remove(x, root);
    }

    public AnyType findMin()
    {
        if(isEmpty())
            throw new RuntimeException();
        return findMin(root).element;
    }

    public AnyType findMax()
    {
        if(isEmpty())
            throw new RuntimeException();
        return findMax(root).element;
    }

    public boolean contains(AnyType x)
    {
        return contains(x, root);
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return root == null;
    }

    public void printTree()
    {
        if (isEmpty())
            System.out.println("Tree is Empty");
        else
            printTree(root);
    }

    private BinaryNode<AnyType> insert(AnyType x, BinaryNode<AnyType> t)
    {
        if(t==null)
            return new BinaryNode<AnyType>(x,null,null);

        int compareResult = x.compareTo(t.element);

        if(compareResult < 0)
            t.left = insert(x,t.left);
        else if (compareResult > 0)
            t.right = insert(x, t.right);
        else
            ;
        return t;
    }

    private BinaryNode<AnyType> remove(AnyType x, BinaryNode<AnyType> t)
    {
        if(t==null)
            return t;

        int compareResult = x.compareTo(t.element);

        if(compareResult < 0)
            t.left = remove(x, t.left);
        else if(compareResult > 0)
            t.right = remove(x, t.right);
        else if (t.left != null && t.right != null)
        {
            t.element = findMin(t.right).element;
            t.right = remove(t.element, t.right);
        }
        else
            t = (t.left != null) ? t.left : t.right;
        return t;
    }

    private BinaryNode<AnyType> findMin (BinaryNode<AnyType> t)
    {
        if (t == null)
            return null;
        else if (t.left == null)
            return t;
        return findMin(t.left);
    }

    private BinaryNode<AnyType> findMax (BinaryNode<AnyType> t)
    {
        if (t != null)
            while(t.right != null)
                t = t.right;
        return t;
    }

    private boolean contains(AnyType x, BinaryNode<AnyType> t)
    {
        if (t == null)
            return false;

        int compareResult = x.compareTo(t.element);

        if(compareResult < 0)
            return contains(x, t.left);

        else if (compareResult > 0)
            return contains (x, t.right);
        else
            return true;
    }

    private void printTree (BinaryNode<AnyType> t)
    {
        if (t != null)
        {
            printTree(t.left);
            System.out.println(t.element);
            printTree(t.right);
        }
    }

    private int height(BinaryNode<AnyType> t)
    {
        if (t == null)
            return -1;
        else
            return 1 + Math.max(height(t.left), height(t.right));
    }

    private static class BinaryNode<AnyType>
    {
        BinaryNode(AnyType theElement)
        {
            this(theElement, null, null);
        }

        BinaryNode(AnyType theElement, BinaryNode<AnyType> lt, BinaryNode<AnyType> rt)
        {
            element = theElement;
            left = lt;
            right = rt;
        }

        AnyType element;
        BinaryNode<AnyType> left;
        BinaryNode<AnyType> right;
    }
}
```

The Main file:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Clinic c1 = new Clinic();
        BST<Patient> bst = new BST<Patient>();
        try{
            File f = new File("patients.txt");
            Scanner x = new Scanner(f);



            while(x.hasNextLine()){
                String line = x.nextLine();
                String[] detail = line.split("\t",4);
                String name = detail[0];
                String doctor = detail[1];
                String currApp = detail[2];
                String nextApp = detail[3];
                Patient p = new Patient(name, doctor, currApp, nextApp);
                c1.addPatient(p);
                c1.assignDoctor();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //sort ArrayList of patients
        Collections.sort(c1.patientList, new Comparator<Patient>(){
            @Override
            public int compare(Patient o1, Patient o2){
                return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
            }
        });
        List<Patient> list = new ArrayList<Patient>();

        for (Patient p: list){
            bst.insert(p);
        }
        bst.printTree();
    }
}
```

Patient file:

```
public class Patient implements Comparable<Patient>{
    private String patientName;
    private String doctorName;
    private String  currAppt;
    private String nextAppt;

    Patient (String patientName,String doctorName ,String currAppt, String    nextAppt)
    {
        this.patientName= patientName;
        this.doctorName = doctorName;
        this.currAppt = currAppt;
        this.nextAppt= nextAppt;
    }   

    public String getDoctor()
    {return doctorName;}

    public String getName()
    {
        return patientName;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return (patientName+" "+doctorName+" "+currAppt +" "+ nextAppt);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Patient o) {
        if (patientName.equals(o))
        return 0;
        return patientName.compareTo(o.patientName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your clinic class as well?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please take some time to visit the [help] and also read [ask].  Questions of the form "here's my code, please debug it" are considered off-topic. StackOverflow is not a discussion, tutorial or debugging site. The way this works is you are expected to attempt to solve the problem and then ask for help when you run into a difficulty, explaining clearly what you have tried and what you don't understand. At a minimum you should already have stepped through the code in an IDE debugger and be able to identify results that don't match your expectation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this part:

```
List<Patient> list = new ArrayList<Patient>();

for (Patient p: list){
    bst.insert(p);
}
```

You initialize list to be an empty array list and then loop over the empty list and add any patients. Since it is empty, that loop never adds anything to the BST. My guess is you actually meant to use the c1.patientList there. So:

```
List<Patient> list = new ArrayList<Patient>();

for (Patient p: c1.patientList){
    bst.insert(p);
}
```